# InterviewBit: Giving run time error on submit but correct output on custom test case

Tags: c++, c++11, runtime-error, stdvector, testcase

Solved a question on interviewBit, here's the question's URL:
https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/first-missing-integer/

Below is my solution to the question above. It passed the test cases, but on submit gives a *runtime error*. I used the test case(that resulted in runtime error) as custom input and it gave me the correct answer but is giving an error for same input on submit.

```
int Solution::firstMissingPositive(vector<int> &A) 
{
    int n = A.size();
    int temp;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        while(A[i]!=0 && A[i]!=(i+1))
        {
            if(A[i]<0 || A[i]>(n+1))
            {
                A[i] = 0;
                break;
            }
            temp = A[A[i]-1];
            if(temp == A[i])
            {
                A[i] = 0;
                break;
            }
            A[A[i]-1] = A[i];
            A[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        if(A[i] == 0)
            return i+1;

    return n+1;
}
```

Here is the input that is giving the error:

```
A : [ 885, 49, 624, 223, 604, 290, 814, 978, 507, 801, 19, 60, 952, 858, 434, 202, 417, 222, 431, 939, 460, 563, 121, 11, 178, 498, 187, 69, 997, 693, 2, 807, 428, 146, 232, 226, 595, 888, 323, 446, 995, 572, 193, 941, 958, 110, 415, 85, 613, 672, 76, 492, 404, 512, 961, 79, 551, 830, 550, 215, 938, 495, 47, 650, 137, 684, 412, 608, 573, 688, 583, 558, 922, 977, 852, 350, 590, 540, 91, 979, 441, 651, 191, 863, 177, 519, 494, 116, 705, 93, 571, 960, 399, 733, 210, 349, 150, 715, 103, 501, 867, 985, 55, 273, 821, 837, 165, 487, 881, 70, 266, 557, 40, 175, 873, 905, 260, 470, 287, 132, 744, 379, 197, 876, 765, 764, 190, 477, 388, 546, 423, 599, 944, 0, 853, 974, 825, 12, 288, 250, 95, 815, 88, 471, 251, 575, 656, 303, 252, 33, 701, 751, 302, 908, 928, 516, 225, 56, 27, 972, 199, 696, 481, 112, 524, 510, 3, 51, 459, 576, 490, 690, 817, 936, 683, 24, 111, 98, 36, 409, 694, 544, 981, 126, 552, 10, 262, 520, 92, 826, 341, 169, 778, 168, 109, 474, 812, 537, 398, 569, 965, 525, 308, 882, 970, 97, 937, 834, 192, 703, 44, 389, 753, 188, 526, 649, 464, 681, 654, -4, 666, 851, 312, 754, 759, 829, 809, 739, 547, 108, 154, 353, 402, 602, 89, 860, 257, 380, 983, 361, 741, 297, 475, 374, 281, 641, 768, 644, 171, 596, 400, 306, 279, 879, 271, 331, 275, 345, 315, 820, 625, 700, 915, 285, 849, 186, 774, 296, 248, 736, 597, 623, 236, 72, 131, 82, 500, 966, 793, 220, 276, 143, 369, 430, 722, 685, 906, 871, 545, 914, 41, 289, 413, 757, 721, 234, 891, 847, 230, 671, 376, 844, 322, 496, 338, 54, -5, 246, 450, 463, 141, 589, 710, 270, 184, 397, 969, 621, 337, 421, 219, 676, 601, 195, 410, 235, 896, 280, 828, 709, 670, 564, 503, 788, 677, 574, 253, 585, 277, 205, 682, 484, 930, 775, 461, 691, 607, 78, 62, 362, 218, 870, 875, 925, 180, 424, 582, 803, 456, 872, 992, 122, 124, 1, 796, 580, 255, 314, 805, 493, 390, 45, 505, 486, 63, 194, 105, 777, 723, 762, 67, 927, 626, 360, 984, 617, 895, 144, 26, 810, 57, 365, 278, 300, 702, 125, 170, 868, 94, 662, 395, 344, 29, 87, 923, 577, 508, 269, 325, 902, 443, 286, 556, 200, 561, 746, 658, 562, 452, 549, 433, 203, 201, 592, 749, 634, 167, 1000, 130, 559, 536, 811, 384, 99, 675, 818, 394, 106, 310, 789, 104, 7, 994, 172, 955, 832, 209, 655, 164, 5, 633, 71, 734, 692, 378, 638, 720, 769, 976, 22, 28, 845, 932, 877, 884, 823, 163, 462, 299, 964, 699, 737, 35, 567, 328, 258, 565, 115, 779, 320, 657, 647, 594, 96, 153, 515, 282, 640, 698, 30, 856, 313, 637, 735, 136, 591, 643, 504, 748, 373, 429, 578, 618, 242, 151, 432, 848, 836, 305, 155, 513, 207, 783, 46, 921, 227, 954, 802, -2, 13, 8, 738, 465, 541, 4, 53, 90, 973, 158, 560, 497, 732, 534, 444, 58, 950, 107, 975, 133, 447, 39, 342, 364, 422, 996, 893, 479, 615, 761, 457, 396, 689, 272, 864, 368, 233, 511, 138, 478, 383, 747, 183, 947, 445, 473, 946, 483, 797, 74, 543, 943, 239, 448, 135, 321, 48, 800, 907, 245, 329, 528, 588, 850, 953, 386, 819, 653, 147, 185, 790, 743, 869, 630, 962, 440, 142, 667, 480, 145, 646, 437, 926, 318, 64, 23, 499, 911, 489, 140, 238, 241, 16, 659, 419, 901, 990, 890, 224, 42, 718, 264, 502, 77, 216, 458, 86, 123, 910, 405, 455, 317, 614, 406, 229, 772, 660, 728, 942, 841, 468, 442, 166, 372, 382, 340, 758, 714, 249, 887, 956, 668, 740, 332, 327, 17, 917, 522, 918, 127, 31, 785, 83, 326, 795, 593, 712, 292, 274, 566, 206, 548, 934, 991, 295, 542, 117, 371, 695, 50, 968, 284, 824, 449, 359, 780, 298, 533, 59, 988, 346, 356, 100, 467, 357, 265, 488, 669, 792, 605, 21, 18, 358, 897, 861, 408, 716, 173, 579, 427, 217, 530, 951, 933, 855, 181, 854, 179, 159, 606, 213, 554, 986, 827, 664, 352, 945, 244, 418, 304, 335, 711, 268, 636, 128, 102, 212, 293, 261, 411, 334, 661, 330, 900, 139, 301, 34, 706, 336, 892, 333, 663, 846, 482, 61, 598, 929, 784, 451, 231, 517, 134, 294, 899, 679, 176, 931, 527, 152, 439, 948, 766, 348, 767, 189, 20, 909, 963, 998, 538, 387, 898, 267, 628, 414, 609, 32, 904, 466, 916, 838, 756, 214, 529, 889, 454, 835, 773, 208, 570, 426, 755, 687, 407, 770, 354, 161, 425, 43, 113, 673, 752, 648, 782, 859, 523, 874, 211, 196, 612, 704, 713, 993, 535, 760, 256, 619, 81, 472, 611, 120, 865, 15, 80, 610, 539, 999, 729, 982, 989, 959, 750, 967, 149, 629, 678, 377, 118, 532, 420, 616, 833, 148, 857, 745, 75, 639, 957, 156, 391, 237, 521, 469, 518, 385, 553, 243, 416, 600, 725, 584, 631, 319, 831, 924, 940, 727, 392, 808, 581, 52, 717, 393, 886, 674, 101, 38, 6, 568, 401, 587, 367, 324, 506, 375, 436, 798, 254, 913, 307, 355, 84, 843, 9, 794, 403, 980, 791, 182, 665, 119, 311, 25, 620, 816, 381, 240, 157, 804, 263, 920, 309, 622, 160, 283, 228, 822, 726, 627, 935, 73, 878, 880, 866, 453, 291, 652, 555, 343, -3, 66, 438, 949, 485 ]
```

and expected output for above input is:

```
14
```

and the error:

> Runtime Error. Your submission stopped because of a runtime error. ex:
>   division by zero, array index out of bounds, uncaught exception You
>   can try testing your code with custom input and try putting debug
>   statements in your code.
>
> ```
> solution: malloc.c:2374: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof> (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
> Aborted
> ```

Help please.

Comment: I think its time for you to run this in a debugger with the input that failed.

Comment: Suggestion: replace all of the `[]` with `at` and see if the program throws an exception on your computer.

Comment: your input has less than 885 entries, but still you are accessing things like `A[A[i]]`

Comment: uh sorry just discovered the bounds checking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
        if(A[i]<0 || A[i]>(n+1)){
            A[i] = 0;
            break;
        }
        temp = A[A[i]-1];
```

you are checking the bounds, but anything between and including `A[i]==0` and `A[i]==n+1` will pass.

Now consider `A[i]==n+1` then you are accessing `A[A[i]-1] == A[n]` which is one too far.

I understand your code too little to suggest a fix, but in general using `at()` instead of `operator[]` can help a lot to spot such mistakes.

Comment: Oh man, such a silly mistake....just need to add an equals to sign in { if(A[i]<0 || A[i]>=(n+1)) }..........solution is finally accepted just after making the above change, Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer to your question. However thought to show you simpler way.

It's look like you are thinking too much for this simple algorithm.
From `1` to `n` binary search the missing integer in the given sorted vector using `std::binary_search()`. If not found, that's your answer. Even-though this has a time complexity of *O(nlongn)*, has passed all TC.

Try this:

```
int solution(std::vector<int>& A)
{
    std::sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    int ans = 1;
    int n = A[A.size()-1]+1;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; ++i )
    {
       if ( !(std::binary_search (A.begin(), A.end(), i)) )
        {
           ans = i;
           break;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Saufen, but there is a clear constraint of "O(n) time complexity and constant space" in the question, so even though your code passes successfully, it is not a valid solution.
P.S. I also solved it using hashmap in O(n) time but space complexity was O(n) too, hence the need for the above code.

Comment: @AkshitAgarwal regarding interviewbit.com : I felt a bit wired compared to other online completion sites. For the test case 0 1 2 , I should have got 3 as answer. However, after compiling, it has taken only two of my array elements(0 and 2) and gave me an answer 1. In short not so trust worthy. Sometimes their TC/ correctness measures could go wrong.

Comment: hmm, I can't disagree, have encountered similar incidents before, specially in terms of the constraints mentioned (just like above, where your O(nlogn) solution got accepted), but still its an average place for revising the concepts but not too good for high competitive programming.